# setting time on server using php script

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

currently I have a small php script that should be used for setting time on a remote server(in this case a Raspberry Pi 3 running Jessie).

The script is following:

```
<?php
  $curr_time = $_POST["time"];
  echo "Changing to " . $curr_time;
  shell_exec("bash /var/www/html/bash/change_time.sh \" . $curr_time . \"");
  echo "end changing"
?>
```

The new time has to be set as the same time as browser of the client. That time has been passed as a POST variable to the script.

The script for configuration of time works when is being run directly from server with the time Format obtained from JavaScript, but when I try to run it using PHP it does not work.

I also added WWW-data to sudoers(I know it is a bad thing to do but the server is only local, so it is not connected to the Internet).

Can you point me in a right direction on how to make this script work? Thanks!!!

Comment: run this script by over user. for example `root` but the bad way

Comment: do you mean as `sudo bash /var/www/html/change_time.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the command `date` in linux. So if you pass timestamp as seconds, you can use this command in php:

```
shell_exec("date -s @1458644762");
```

Comment: Is this timestamp in UNIX time? Since 1 Jan 1970? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, try this: take the time given in this website and use the command in your linux : http://www.epochconverter.com/